# Need more efficient code to write sum of rank one matrices

Tags: python, arrays, linear-algebra

My goal is to compute a matrix using rank one approximations given by the SVD. For example, after computing

```
M=np.array([[3,0],[4,5]])
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(M)
```

I eventually computed M as the sum

```
s[0]*np.matmul(np.array([[u[0][0]],[u[1][0]]]),np.array([vt[0,:]]))+s[1]*np.matmul(np.array([[u[0][1]],[u[1][1]]]),np.array([vt[1,:]]))
```

Clearly, I need some help doing this more efficiently.  How should I clean this up?

Comment: Hello, For code optimization please submit to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is off-topic for stackoverflow, and should be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all use slicing instead of accessing each element.

No need to use np.array() again if the slicing is proper.

```
s[0]*np.matmul(u[:,0:1],vt[0:1,:])+s[1]*np.matmul(u[:,1:],vt[1:,:])
```